# match against mysql query against multiple tables with the same fields

Tags: php, mysql

Current query:

```
select * from `table1` where MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST ('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND `price` BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 order by MATCH (`product_name`) AGAINST ('test' IN BOOLEAN MODE) desc, `price` DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

How can I run the above query on multiple tables with the same fields? eg table2, table3, table4

Would the query be faster if I were to combine all the data from all tables into 1 single table instead of multiple tables? Or would it make no difference at all?

Answer (score -1):

**Answer to 1st question** : You can use `JOINS` in MySQL,that combines table as you say.

**Answer to 2nd question** :

*One way*  :

```
SELECT
    table1.this, table2.that, table2.somethingelse
FROM
    table1, table2
WHERE
    table1.foreignkey = table2.primarykey
    AND (some other conditions)
```

*Second way :*

```
SELECT
    table1.this, table2.that, table2.somethingelse
FROM
    table1 INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.foreignkey = table2.primarykey
WHERE
    (some other conditions)
```

The `WHERE` syntax is more relational model oriented where `INNER JOIN` is ANSI syntax which you should use.

The first query using `WHERE` become much much more confusing, hard to read, and hard to maintain once you need to start adding more tables to your query. Imagine doing that same query and type of join on four or five different tables ... it's a nightmare.

However, depending on the query optimizer, they may have the same meaning to the machine.

You should always code to be readable.

That is to say, if this is a built-in relationship, use the explicit join. if you are matching on weakly related data, use the `where` clause on the result set obtained from `JOINS`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Not my downvote, but `JOIN` is probably incorrect; the operation needed for "multiple tables with the same fields" is `UNION`.

Comment: yes, the downvote is mine and precisely for this reason. The answer is long, but misses the point entirely (confuses joins and unions).